# How to convert high AC voltage generator to DC voltage to charge a capacitor

Tags: ac, dc, high-voltage, generator, pulse

I have bought several high voltage generator which outputs AC voltage. I wish to convert this high AC voltage to DC voltage to charge a capacitor. I have tried connecting the output (10kV) to a 20kV rated diode and to a 5kV rated capacitor, all in series.

However, it didn't seem to work because the measured DC voltage across the capacitor is too low (600V). Also when I tried to short the capacitor terminals with a screw driver, I observed a small continuous spark which made me think the voltage across the capacitor terminal is not exactly DC.

[image]

[image]

```
Parameter:
PCB size: 5.4x1.8 cm
Voltage and current: DC 3-5V, 5A, 15W. Recommend 3.7V 18650 lithium battery.
Output pulse voltage: 0.5kv-0.8kv
Working frequency: 20khz-25khz
Arc distance: 5-8 mm
```

Comment: Stop this project. The fact you wonder why you could not get kV out of a circuit labelled as outputting 800V, and then think that hooking up diodes and capacitors rated for kiloVolts will somehow produce kiloVolts, and then try to short capacitors with a screw driver means you do not have anywhere near enough experience or caution to keep yourself alive.

Comment: @user1502776:  That description of the high voltage module says "0.5kV to 0.8kV."  That's 500V to 800V, and very far from your "10kV."  If you want help this, you'll need to post a schematic diagram of how you connected things.  I would, however, suggest you stop playing with it until you've got a better grasp of things work.

Comment: You can't even measure 5kV, let alone 10kV, without a special meter and probes nor can you use normal wire. So in your post, when you measured 600V, did you use a regular multi-meter and probes to try and see if it was 10kV? You're lucky because if it actually was 10kV, something bad would have happened not just to your meter but to you. The arc could have jumped onto your probes and fingers before you even touched the terminals.

Comment: Actually, I use 10 to 1, 100 Mohm divider so yeah I can measure very high voltages.